# How to calculate list objects together in java?

Tags: java

Now I have a list populated with different type of products. I need to perform calculations inside the list in a following manner; If condition 1 is false, I need to add the price of the product to total.
If condition 1 is true, i need to subtract the price from total. Basically I need to create a credit receipt. In this case condition 1 tells with boolean if the product has been reimbursed.

My code so far:

```
  private List<Transaction> lsta;

  public void receipt() {
    try {
      List<Transaction> lst = gvar.get(prd);
      boolean executed = false;
      for (Transaction tra : lst) {
        //execute only once
        if (tra.isHasCondition1 == true && !executed) {
          total = tra.getPrice();
          System.out.println("Total before calculation: " + total);
          total = total - tra.getPurseCredit();
          if (total < 0) {
            total = Math.abs(-total);
            System.out.println("Total after Math.abs: " + total);

          } else {
            total = total + tra.getPrice();
          }
          executed = true;
          lsta.add(tra);
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I understand that in my code, it doesn't go trough the whole list per item and add or subtract the price from total. How to accomplish this in Java?

Math.abs function is to remove a minus sign, since sometimes the prices can be negatives on the db.

Also whenever the user clicks the receipt on frontend the receipt() method runs. Thats why I added boolean executed to run it only once.

Comment: Hopefully. I just cannot copy-paste the whole code because of information security reasons. It's a delicate process, trust me.

Comment: Still not clear to me what your problem is. I assume you are not getting the result that you want. What result do you want? What result are you actually getting with your current code?

Comment: Give us the code of the whole procedure. The `catch` block is missing. Since your code is not well formatted, the individual code areas are difficult to see. The test for `total < 0` and the subsequent `total = Math.abs (-total)` seems strange to me. As soon as `executed = true` the `if` branch is never executed again.

Comment: Now it seems to go trough just one instance of possible product items. For example If I have 1 item with condition1 = true and 1 item with condition 1 = false it works. But if the list has 2 items with condition1 = true and 1 item with condition = false. It poduces something like total - price + price. Where it should be total - price - price + price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do but I put in code to reflect my interpretation.  Hopefully, this may guide you to the correct solution.  But first, some observations.

- the boolean `executed` won't do what you want because you set it to false after receipt is called.  You should have it set somewhere per customer and it should be outside of your for loop (why process any of the list if it has already been processed?)
- For using absolute value to correct negative prices, just do it when you get the price. Your if/else with `Math.abs` doesn't make sense.  Just do `price = Math.abs(tra.getPrice())` once for each transaction and use it thru out that transaction.
- In your opening explanation, you don't mention what `purseCredit` is used for or why it is subtracted along with price.  More explanation would help us help you.
- Where is your variable named `total` defined.  Is this a running total?  You have what appear to be debug print statements but where do you generate the actual receipt.  That might also help explain what you are trying to do.
- finally, as always it is helpful to have some actual data and expected output.  Include your complete Transaction's class or a minimal version that would work in a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```
public static void receipt() {
    try {
        List<Transaction> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        double total = 0;
        if (!executed) {
            for (Transaction tra : lst) {
                double price = Math.abs(tra.getPrice());
                
                if (tra.isHasCondition1) {
                    total -= price;  // you want to subtract price and purseCredit ?
                    total = total - tra.getPurseCredit();
                    
                } else {
                    total += price;
                }
                lsta.add(tra);
            }
        }
        executed = true;
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This did guided me to the correct solution. First the executed boolean will be set false by another method, which searches the transactions to the screen and now running the receipt method sets it true, so that if the user calls the receipt method multimple times the calculations won't happen again. Math.abs is now only executed if the added value is a negative number. Critical realization here was, that when creating a credit receipt, I don't need to subtract the negated value from the total(reimburse cancels itself out). Total just reprecents a total price of all products on a receipt.

Comment: I will provide a more detailed answer about the solution when I have completed a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 1):

I would work with streams in this case. The methods `addToTotal` and `substractFromTotal` should be clear.

Example:

```
double result = lst.stream()
    .reduce(
        0d, // startvalue
        (total, transaction) -> { // accumulator which adds the values
          if (transaction.isHasCondition1()) {
            return addToTotal(total, transaction);
          } else {
            return subtractFromTotal(total, transaction);
          }
        }, 
        (a, b) -> a + b // combiner, only used with parallel streams
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Looks like the give code has some issue and its looks incomplete.
// However u can move the executed field as static. replace the enhanced for loop //with iterator or regular for loop

    static boolean executed = false;
    static long total = 0;
    public  void receipt() {
        try {
            List<Transaction> lst = Stream.of(new Solution.Transaction(12, 120, false)).collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (int i=0; i<lst.size() ; i++) {
                //execute only once
                if (lst.get(i).isHasCondition1 == false && !executed) {
                    total = lst.get(i).getPrice();
                    System.out.println("Total before calculation: " + total);
                    total = total + lst.get(i).getPurseCredit();
                    if (total < 0) {
                        total = Math.abs(-total);
                        System.out.println("Total after Math.abs: " + total);
                    }
                    executed = true;
                    lst.add(lst.get(i));
                }else {
                    System.out.println(" is hasa condition true");
                    total = total - lst.get(i).getPrice();
                }
            }
        }finally {
            System.out.println("completed") ;
        }
    }

    static class Transaction{
        boolean isHasCondition1;

        long price;
        long purseCredit;
        Transaction(long price, long purseCredit, boolean isHasCondition1){
                this.isHasCondition1  = isHasCondition1;
                this.price = price;
                this.purseCredit  = purseCredit;
        }

        public long getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        public long getPurseCredit() {
            return purseCredit;
        }

        public boolean isHasCondition1() {
            return isHasCondition1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide explanation to what this: "Stream.of(new Solution.Transaction(12, 120, false)).collect(Collectors.toList());" does?

Comment: it was added just for testing purpose n local system. it returns a list.